# How bad is it to show Parse object id's to user?

Tags: ios, security, parse-platform, qr-code

I have a built in QR Code scanner in my iOS app. My backend runs on Parse, and I want the user to be able to pick certain objects on the app and encode their id's into a QR Code and share it around so that users can later scan a QR code, receive the object id's, and query them on the database to later fetch and display them somewhere.

However, what is stopping someone from using a QR scanner outside my app, looking at the object id's encoded into the QR, and messing something up? How bad is it to somehow allow users to see the object id of an entry in your Parse database? Will this heavily compromise security?

I thought about encrypting the object id's but am afraid my app will be rejected by Apple because of not following proper standards. What do you guys suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: **No.**

There is no major security risk in giving away object IDs.  Unless the 3rd parties had access to your app keys, then there is no way for them to access your data, even if they already knew everything about it.  As long as you keep your app keys well hidden, there is no way your users can change anything outwith what you've de

Remember that your object ID's are only unique in the scope of your app (perhaps only even in the scope of that particular class), so when they find the object ID, they don't know if it's your app, my app, or anyone else's app - to them, it is as useful as holding a random set of digits.

The bigger issue I would say is that you cannot set the object IDs, so if for whatever reason that line is deleted, you can reinstate every part of it, but they'll all have different object IDs.  This would mean your users running around with meaningless QR codes.  Sure you can restore from a backup, but you'll lose any other changes since then.  This is why I would **never** recommend indexing using Object IDs, rather that you create a new column "ID" that can then be changed by you, and then scripting a piece of cloud code logic in the side to ensure it is unique.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Any tips on how to best protect the app keys and secrets? I know these are in the AppDelegate class, so could someone see the source code of my app and get it?

Comment: @user5684631 Not easily.  I'm not going to say ta impossible to decode an app binary to get your keys, but Apple encodes your source into binary before distribution, so the app keys can't be easily viewed.  You'd need to figure the encoding, and decode the app - which is far far beyond the vast majority of people.

Comment: Also if your app doesn't need to change this data, you can use Parse's permissions system to stop people from editing the data without authenticating (which you would not include in the binary).  In that case they would be able to see your data but not change it.  But like I said, the odds of this happening are so minimal

Answer (score 0):

Sharing the object ID is not an issue, so long as your app has proper security. Hopefully your app's security does not rely on keeping the object ID secret.

Encryption is fine in iOS apps, so long as you file the proper paperwork. One of my apps uses a very high level of encryption and is available in every country, except France. You just need to file the correct paperwork and it's not that hard to do.